# Boost xml_parser to format empty tag

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use `boost::property_tree::read_xml` and `write_xml` to copy from a xml file and generate a new xml file with same content. The problem I found is this `write_xml` function always generate empty tags which are not desired. For example, if the original content is :

```
<a></a>
```

the output would become:

```
<a/>
```

so is it possible for me to change `boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings` to avoid empty tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most importantly, it bears repeating that Boost does **not** have an XML library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check sources of library. I compared two versions 1.47 and 1.66, in both the implementation is the same and looks as follows

```
    // Write element
    if (pt.data().empty() && pt.empty())    // Empty key
    {
        if (indent >= 0)
        {
            write_xml_indent(stream,indent,settings);
            stream << Ch('<') << key << 
                      Ch('/') << Ch('>');
            if (want_pretty)
                stream << Ch('\n');
        }
    }
    else    // Nonempty key
```

so the answer is no, by using `xml_writer_settings` you cannot change writing empty tag, the format is always `<KEY/>`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also checked and changed the source code. It works fine so far and no empty tag is generated. But I don't really know whether this will lead to an unexpected error in the future.